# is there a command to apply hlint suggestions in emacs?

Tags: haskell, emacs, flycheck, hlint

I'm using flycheck and haskell-hlint in emacs when I write Haskell codes
and I think it will be great if I can apply those hlint suggestions by invoking some emacs procedures instead of modifying the code manually.

If there isn't one available and in case I have to write this procedure for myself:

Is it guaranteed that hlint output is always of the following form:

```
Found:
  {Text1}
Why not:
  {Text2}
```

where `{Text?}` can always be parsed as a Haskell abstract syntax tree?

Comment: `Text2` isn't necessarily Haskell syntax. One example is the "Reduce duplication" warning, which says `Why not: Combine with Foo/Bar/Baz.hs:123:4`

Comment: @fjh I see, so my strategy can apply to certain suggestions, but not all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HLint comes with an Emacs script [hs-lint.el](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/hlint/data/hs-lint.el) that does the replacement you are after, details are in the [README](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint#emacs-integration). The script isn't officially supported by the HLint developer, but some people have had some success with it.

Separately, there are plans to provide a proper replacement feature in HLint, which if provided would be easy to integrate with Emacs. While it's always been on the back-burner, there are now people working on the necessary whitespace-aware-syntax-replacement libraries that HLint requires.

Comment: This is an old answer. Is there any progress on this front? (For future readers, too)

Answer (score 2):

There is an [HLint Refactor Mode](https://github.com/mpickering/hlint-refactor-mode) building on the [apply-refact](https://github.com/mpickering/apply-refact) tool that provides HLint replacements in Emacs.